How to Manipulate API Responses with Middleware in Next.js?
How can I use middleware in my Next.js application to catch and manipulate responses received from an external API?
The function below is executed from a Server Component.
export async function fetchData() {

  const response = await fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/endpoint');

  if(!response.ok) { throw new Error('Failed to fetch data') }

  return response

}

Here is my endpoint located inside the file /app/api/endpoint/route.tsx:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {

  const apiResponse = await fetch('https://my-external-api.com/endpoint');

  //Do something that's useful in the middleware

  const data = await apiResponse.json()

  return NextResponse.json(data)
}

Here is my /src/middleware.tsx
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const middleware = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  console.log(request)
  console.log(NextResponse)
}

export default middleware;

I need to make some changes to the response sent back to the fetchData() function. I could do it in the route handler itself, but that would mean a lot of code repetition.
